# Splitting Pandas dataframe into multiple dataframes based on condition in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

To prep my data correctly for a ML task, I need to be able to split my original dataframe into multiple smaller dataframes. I want to get all the rows above and including the row where the value for column 'BOOL' is 1 - for every occurrence of 1. i.e. n dataframes where n is the number of occurences of 1.

A sample of the data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"USER_ID": ['001', '001', '001', '001', '001'],
'VALUE' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "BOOL": [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]})
```

Expected Output is 2 dataframes as shown:

[image]

And:

[image]

I have considered a for loop using if-else statements to append rows - but it is highly inefficient for the data-set I am using. Looking for a more pythonic way of doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) which accepts an array of indices where to split:

```
np.split(df, *np.where(df.BOOL == 1))
```

If you want to include the rows with `BOOL == 1` to the previous data frame you can just add 1 to all the indices:

```
np.split(df, np.where(df.BOOL == 1)[0] + 1)
```

Comment: Works like a charm, but how do I access each of the resulting dataframes?

Comment: @Ash What do you mean by "access"? The function returns a list that contains all the data frames so you can access that list. Note that the indices are retained within each of the sub-data frames.

Comment: `np.split(df, np.where(df.BOOL == 1)[0] + 1)` dose not work also you split the dataframe to 3 , I think he need 0 to n (n is BOOL ==1 index )

Comment: @Wen-Ben Why not? It does work for the given example and it won't raise an error even if the indices run out of range; in that case you just get empty data frames.

Comment: @a_guest I think in his expected output he need two dataframe(0-1 and 0-3) , and you return 3  , each of the length is 2,2,1 am I right ?

Comment: @a_guest Yes, just realised. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks mate.

Comment: @Wen-Ben In case that is required one can use an additional `it.accumulate(df_split, lambda *x: pd.concat(x))`. Though in terms of efficiency it's probably not the best way to go about it.

Comment: Wow, pandas never cease to amaze me with just how clunky the API can be.

Answer (score 3):

I think using for loop is better here

```
idx=df.BOOL.nonzero()[0]

d={x : df.iloc[:y+1,:] for x , y in enumerate(idx)}
d[0]
   BOOL USER_ID  VALUE
0     0     001      1
1     1     001      2
```

Comment: Really good approach - which works on the sample dataset. But for some cryptic reason does not work on my actual dataframe. It returns n dataframes - all of the original size.

Comment: @Ash anyway , I just follow your expected output(above two pics)

Comment: @Wen-Ben You mix `index` and `iloc` that's probably the reason why it doesn't work for the other data frame (in case the indices there are not a simple enumeration).

Comment: @Wen-Ben But now for non-numeric indices the `+1` will fail. So you should probably stick to iloc and use the positions of the index.

Comment: @a_guest check nonzero

Answer (score 2):

Why not list comprehension? like:

```
>>> l=[df.iloc[:i+1] for i in df.index[df['BOOL']==1]]
>>> l[0]
   BOOL USER_ID  VALUE
0     0     001      1
1     1     001      2
>>> l[1]
   BOOL USER_ID  VALUE
0     0     001      1
1     1     001      2
2     0     001      3
3     1     001      4
>>>
```

Comment: Simplifies @Wen-Ben's approach to 1 line - but I still have the same issue. Works on the sample dataset. But not on my actual dataframe. This returns n dataframes - all of the original size.

Comment: You mix `index` and `iloc` that's probably the reason why it doesn't work for the other data frame (in case the indices there are not a simple enumeration).

Comment: @a_guest Sorry mate, can you explain what you mean? Not quite sure I understand what you mean by mix index and iloc?

Comment: @Ash `iloc` returns the index *position* while `loc` uses indices *themselves*. So for your example there's not difference as your index is `[0, 1, 2, 4, 5]` and the indices match their positions. However if you used for example `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` as index, then `df.index[df.BOOL == 1]` would return `['b', 'd']` while `iloc` expects the corresponding positions, i.e. `[1, 3]`. `loc` on the other hand does expect indices however then you can't do the increment `i + 1`. So in that case you should stick to `index_position = df.BOOL.nonzero()[0] + 1` and use it together with `df.iloc[:i]`.