# Groupby consecutive values and aggregate

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataset (pandas DataFrame `df`):

```
DateTime              INDICATOR
2017-01-01 10:35:00   0
2017-01-01 10:40:00   0
2017-01-01 10:45:00   0
2017-01-01 10:50:00   0
2017-01-01 10:55:00   0
2017-01-01 11:00:00   0
2017-01-01 11:05:00   1
2017-01-01 11:10:00   1
2017-01-01 11:15:00   1
2017-01-01 11:20:00   1
2017-01-01 11:25:00   0
2017-01-01 11:30:00   0
2017-01-01 11:35:00   1
2017-01-01 11:40:00   1
2017-01-01 11:45:00   1
```

The column `DateTime` is of the type `datetime64[ns]`.

I want to obtain the duration (in minutes) of the data segments where `INDICATOR` is equal to 1.

The expected result is:

```
[15, 10]
```

This is how I tried to solve this task but I receive all 0 values:

```
s=df["INDICATOR"].eq(1)
df1=df[s].copy()
s1=df1.groupby(s.cumsum())["DateTime"].transform(lambda x : x.max()-x.min()).dt.seconds
```

All values of `s1` are 0.

Answer (score 3):

First, create groupID by using:

```
gb_ID = df.INDICATOR.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
```

Next, pick only `INDICATOR == 1` and doing `groupby` by `gb_ID`. Find `max`, `min` of `DateTime` per gb_ID. Find `diff` of this `max`, `min`. Finally, pick columns not `NaT` to convert it to int of minutes and call `values` to return array.

```
df.query('INDICATOR == 1').groupby(gb_ID)['DateTime'].agg(['min', 'max']) \
                          .diff(axis=1)['max'].dt.seconds.floordiv(60).values

Out[351]: array([15, 10], dtype=int64)
```

---

Below is the dataframe before picking non-`NaT` and `values`

```
df.query('INDICATOR == 1').groupby(gb_ID)['DateTime'].agg(['min', 'max']).diff(axis=1)

Out[362]:
          min      max
INDICATOR
2         NaT 00:15:00
4         NaT 00:10:00
```

Comment: Could you please explain what was wrong with my solution?

Comment: `s` returns `True`  on every `INDICATOR.eq(1)`.  `s.cumsum` will increase each row of `INDICATOR.eq(1)` by 1 such as `'...1,  2,  3,  4...'` and  `'...5, 6, 7'`. Groupby on these values separate each row into a single-row groups (group having one row), so their `max` is also `min`. I.e, `max` - `min` = 0

Comment: Why eq(1) returns True for all cases, even those that are equal to 0? This is what I do not understand.

Comment: No, it only returns True on `INDICATOR = 1`. As in your sample data, `df["INDICATOR"].eq(1)` returns a series where row 0 - 5: `False`, 6 - 9: `True`, 10 - 11: `False`, 12 - 14: `True`. You then index/slice  `True-only` rows to `df1` by command `df1=df[s].copy()`. You finally work on `df1`. In the other words, in the last step, you work on the sub-dataframe containing only `True` rows.

Answer (score 0):

Taking [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54498938/splitting-pandas-dataframe-into-multiple-dataframes-based-on-condition-in-column) into account I was thinking to split the dataframe into subframes with [`np.split()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html).

Try this:

```
from numpy import nan

# split df on condition that indicator is 0
splitted_dfs = np.split(df, *np.where(df. INDICATOR == 0))

results = []

for split in splitted_dfs:
    # iloc[1:] omits the first 0 entry of the splitted df
    results.append(split.iloc[1:].index.max() - split.iloc[1:].index.min())

print([int(x.seconds / 60) for x in results if x.seconds is not nan])

# prints to [15, 10]
```

**Explanation**

`np.split()` with condition `INDICATOR == 0` makes a split on every row where the condition is met. This yields this list of dataframes:

```
2017-01-01 10:35:00          0, INDICATOR

2017-01-01 10:40:00          0, INDICATOR

2017-01-01 10:45:00          0, INDICATOR

2017-01-01 10:50:00          0, INDICATOR

2017-01-01 10:55:00          0, INDICATOR

2017-01-01 11:00:00          0
2017-01-01 11:05:00          1
2017-01-01 11:10:00          1
2017-01-01 11:15:00          1
2017-01-01 11:20:00          1, INDICATOR

2017-01-01 11:25:00          0, INDICATOR

2017-01-01 11:30:00          0
2017-01-01 11:35:00          1
2017-01-01 11:40:00          1
2017-01-01 11:45:00          1
```

You can iterate over that list, ignore the empty ones and remove the first 0 entry of the relevant ones.